# Сервисы Linux Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте. Появилось пару вопросов касательно сервисов в Linux.

**1. irqbalance**
В интернете прочитал, что этот сервер респределяет прерывания между ядрами 
процессора. То есть, если у меня одноядерный процессор, то его можно смело 
отключать?

**2. kmod**
Менеджер модулей ядра. Если я вообще не работаю с модулями, то его можно отключить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. irqbalance**
Если процессор одноядерный и нет HyperThreading, то можно отключить.

**2. kmod**
"Я не работаю с модулями". ***Вы*** можете не работать, но *Ubuntu* в дефолтной конфигурации работает. Можно отключить этот сервис только в том случае, когда ядро монолитное и вы точно знаете, что модулей нет и не будет. В современных дистрибутивах ядра почти всегда модульные.